# Fasttext for Python - module 'fasttext' has no attribute 'load_model'

Tags: python, fasttext

Please forgive my newbness here, but fasttext is not working for me on python. I am using anaconda running python 3.6. My code is as follows(just an example):

```
import fasttext 

model = fasttext.load_model('/home/sproc/share/fastText/model.bin')
print(model.words)
```

This returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/sf_VBoxShare/LiClipseWorkspace/test/testpack/fasttext.py", line 1, in <module>
    import fasttext 
  File "/media/sf_VBoxShare/LiClipseWorkspace/test/testpack/fasttext.py", line 3, in <module>
   model = fasttext.load_model('/home/sproc/share/fastText/model.bin')
AttributeError: module 'fasttext' has no attribute 'load_model'
```

Does the same thing with cbow and skipgram when trying to create word vectors. I check the **init**.py file from the .../site-packages/fasttext directory and it imports said attributes, but they are not part of the model.py module. I'm guessing this has something to do with the shared object file but I am not sure. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like some binary files are missing

Comment: @akshay Any ideas what it could be? I have fasttext(standard c which DOES work) installed under `~/share/fasttext` and I installed fasttext using `pip install fasttext` so I'm not exactly sure what could be the issue.

Comment: Are you using Anaconda. If so the Cython should be able to compile it. If not try to install Anaconda and then re-install it with pip

Comment: I am indeed using Anaconda and have all that goodness installed. Not exactly sure what's going on here.

Comment: Change the file name fasttext.py to something else.
Make sure there are no file named fasttext.{py,pyc} in the current directory

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution that worked for me when I got the error you are getting;

Import FastText

```
from gensim.models.wrappers import FastText
```

Load the binary

```
model=FastText.load_fasttext_format('wiki.simple.bin')
```

Comment: Works fine for me on won 10

Answer (score 3):

Rename your python file . 
Don't name it as fasttext.py .If your name it like this , what you import by "import fasttext.py " will be your own file.
You can rename it as 'fast_text.py' or something else .

Answer (score 1):

If you install [fastText](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/tree/master/python) package instead of the old fasttext, then

```
import fastText 
model = fastText.load_model('/home/sproc/share/fastText/model.bin')
```

should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

@spencerktm30 I recommend you using pyfasttext instead of fasttext which is no longer active and it has a lot of bugs. link to [pyfasttext](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyfasttext/)

Actually, I faced similar issue when trying to load a C++ pre trained model and I had to switch to using pyfasttext to get it to work.

So this should hopefully work for you:

```
>>> from pyfasttext import FastText
>>> model = FastText('/home/sproc/share/fastText/model.bin')
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @MatthiasSeifert I edited the comment I hope it looks better.

Comment: note on the package page as of Dec2018: _"Warning! pyfasttext is no longer maintained: use the official Python binding from the fastText repository"_
https://pypi.org/project/pyfasttext

Answer (score 0):

Rename the file from fasttext.py to another name, it will work.

Comment: that is the same answer that has been given a year ago

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there are different `fasttext` python libraries out there!
[fasttext](https://pypi.org/project/fasttext/) != [fasttext-win](https://pypi.org/project/fasttext-win/)