# load embeddings trained with FastText (two files are generated)

Tags: load, fasttext

I have built embeddings from a source collection. Two files are generated with extensions: embeddings.bin and embeddings.bin.wv.vectors_ngrams.npy

When I carried out the embeddings to another machine, I can't load. So the next error message appears:

AttributeError: 'FastText' object has no attribute 'vocabulary'

I use the next code for loading them:

word_vectors = FastText.load("embeddings.bin", mmap='r')

I created them with the next code:
from gensim.models import FastText
model2 = FastText(vector_size=4, window=3, min_count=1, sentences=common_texts, epochs=10)
model2.save(embeddings.bin)

I have the same version gensim (3.8.0) in both machines, but they were built in Linux, and I want to use them in Windows.

word_vectors = FastText.load("embeddings.bin", mmap='r')

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45377306/fasttext-for-python-module-fasttext-has-no-attribute-load-model

Answer (score 0):

Note that after a `.save()`, there may be many files that all begin with your specified (`embeddings.bin`) filename-prefix - and all of them must be kept together for the model to be `.load()`-able. So first & foremost, check that.

There shouldn't be a problem moving from Linux to Windows, if all files make the move. But maybe the long filenames with multiple internal `.` characters are causing problems on your Windows filesystem, so be sure to verify that after moving them across, they have the same full names. (Also, perhaps, ensure they all made it across as with the same length/checksum, in case any silent corruption/truncation may have occurred.)

Finally, if those don't help, watch the `.save()` and `.load()` for any other errors/tracebacks beyond what you've already shown, which might hint of other things going wrong earlier than you thought. (If there's more info here & you're still struggling, be sure to edit that extra error info into your question text.)

Also: you should probably **not* be using `gensim-3.8.0` (released 2019-07-08). If you have a choice & can retrain, `gensim-4.0.1` has many improvements to the `FastText` implementation. If for some reason you're still stuck using an older Gensim, at least get to the last `3.8.x` release, `gensim-3.8.3`.